# Final class with class and static funcs

Tags: ios, swift

I have two question regarding code below:

```swift
final class God {

    class func eat() {
         print("Om nom nom")
    }

    static func throwLightning() {
         print("Zzap")
    }
}
```

1. Is it possible to override `eat()` method without removing `final` keyword from `God` class?
2. Is there any difference between `class` and `static` funcs in classes marked as `final` ?

UPDATE:

Is there any difference from method dispatch point of view?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to override `eat()` method without removing `final` keyword from God class?

No. "override" is something you do in a subclass. But `final` means there can be no subclasses, so where would this "override" even occur?

> Is there any difference between `class` and `static` funcs in classes marked as `final`?

No, not from a Swift programmer's point of view. `static` means `class final`. But this class is *already* `final`, so saying `static` adds nothing.

Comment: you mentioned `not from a Swift programmer's point of view`, then from which point of view there is difference?

Comment: Is there any difference from method dispatch point of view? Interested in only one case - final class with static and class funcs.

Comment: I was thinking of other languages, like Java or even Objective-C. Anyway, I've answered the question. If you don't like the answer, don't upvote / accept it. Thank you.